# Link to new HTML page in same root folder not working

Tags: html, eclipse, thymeleaf, href

Forgive the stupid question -- i know i'm doing something retarded, but I'm kinda stuck.

I'm a complete newbie -- and I inherited this website that is build on spring, thymeleaf, hibernate,  java and a bunch of other technologies that i'm still learning. The original developer will not take my calls.

All the development is being done on Eclipse -- and I can get the existing project to run and build on my laptop.

I'm trying create a new page and link to it from my main default page (index.htlm).

I can create the href tag to an "existing" html file in the root folder.

But when I reference a new html page in the same directory -- the reference goes to 404.

What am I doing wrong.

Here is the original html snip:

```
        <!-- Contractors  --> 
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 box-shadow 10px 10px " style="padding: 50px">
                    <span class="h1 type--bold">Contractors & Handymen</span><span class="h2">Looking for side hustle?</span>
                    <p class="lead">Be alerted to in-network jobs.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <a th:href="@{/company}" href="company.html"
                               class="btn btn--sm btn--warning"><span
                                    class="btn__text type--uppercase">Register Here</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I created a page in the same directory as "company.html" the file name is "signUpContractor.html"
And I updated the html snip  as such:

```
        <!-- Contractors  --> 
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 box-shadow 10px 10px " style="padding: 50px">
                    <span class="h1 type--bold">Contractors & Handymen</span><span class="h2">Looking for side hustle?</span>
                    <p class="lead">Be alerted to in-network jobs.</p>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <a th:href="@{/signUpContractor}" href="signUpContractor.html"
                               class="btn btn--sm btn--warning"><span
                                    class="btn__text type--uppercase">Register Here</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

output looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noUd8.png)

but when i click the link get this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFE3A.png)

do i need to register the page with thymeleaf? or something?

if i reference other pages in the folder (that was existing prior to me taking over) such as "about.html" or "contactUs.html" the href works just fine. But any new page I create will go to 404.

Thanks for the kind soul that can help me navigate this.

Apologize in advance for the newbie question, i'm just out on the deep-end right now.

:-)

Comment: On further experimentation, i discovered this could be a path issue. If i go to the \webapps\<app>\ folder in my tomcat and directly add this html file (signUpContractor) in that directory AFTER deploying the app -- the link works fine.                                                      
            But now i'm stumped as to how to get eclipse to add to register this new file into the correct directory so the application can find it. In Eclipse, I added this file to the same folder as the other HTML files -- that the apps seems to be able to reference just fine. But any new files: no luck.